# How to stop hyperref package from interfering with pstricks?

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I am honestly at my wits end with this, it has been exhausting trying to track down this bug but I am out of options. I am writing a document that requires extensive diagrams of go boards (a game) for which only the package `psgo` is really suitable. Since I also include png files, I've had to go to xelatex. Using `auto-pst-pdf` isn't an option, it just doesn't work, so xelatex is all I have.

When including the `hyperref` package, any numbered stones in the diagram move out of alignment and ruin the diagram. This is seen in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[]{pstricks}
\usepackage{psgo}
\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgopartialboard*}{(8,6)(14,12)}
        \stone{black}{k}{10}
        \stone{black}{l}{11}
        \stone{black}{k}{11}
        \stone{black}{l}{10}
        \stone{white}{l}{8}
        \stone{white}{k}{9}
        \stone{white}{l}{9}
        \setcounter{gomove}{0}
        \move{j}{10}
        \move{j}{9}
        \move{j}{8}
        \move{j}{7}
\end{psgopartialboard*}
\end{document}
```

I've been using `latexmk -xelatex main.tex --enable-write18` to compile this.

If you duplicate the psgo partial board shown, then it will show `xdvipdfmx:warning: Object @gomove.1 already defined.` as a warning when compiling, but it still works.

I have narrowed it down to an issue (I think) with the way hyperref interfaces with counters, as the counter is necessarily reset with each board. Any static stones, placed without a counter, work just fine. The frustrating thing is that it works perfectly fine through dvipdf but I can't use that for this project.

Is there a way to fix this without losing functionality? I'm in the process of rewriting `psgo`, is there some trick that I can use in there? Hyperref is required by a bunch of other stuff so I don't know what to do here.

Any help with this would be much, much appreciated, please!

Comment: Is there a difference, when you change the order of packages? (6 combinations are possible)

Comment: @MS-SPO No difference at all. And only three combinations, since pstricks needs to be loaded before psgo. Regardless, the problem persists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`psgo` uses `\refstepcounter` (imho unnecessarly) and with hyperref this adds destinations which changes the spacing.

You can suppress the destinations with a boolean.
In a current texlive you can use lualatex for the pstricks. It is much faster than xelatex but for some effects like opacity it requires the new pdfmanagement.

```
%for lualalatex:
\DocumentMetadata{} %required to activate the pdfmanagement
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[]{pstricks}
\usepackage{psgo}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/psgopartialboard*/before}{\@skiphyperreftrue} %\LinkTargetOff in the next hyperref
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{psgopartialboard*}{(8,6)(14,12)}
        \stone{black}{k}{10}
        \stone{black}{l}{11}
        \stone{black}{k}{11}
        \stone{black}{l}{10}
        \stone{white}{l}{8}
        \stone{white}{k}{9}
        \stone{white}{l}{9}
        \setcounter{gomove}{0}
        \move{j}{10}
        \move{j}{9}
        \move{j}{8}
        \move{j}{7}
\end{psgopartialboard*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, this was driving me insane. And thanks for the tip about lualatex, that makes the compiling much much faster